# i wants a service feature just before write post section which configure through my website

Tags: facebook

I want a service feature just before write the post section which configures through my website.
as I post an appointment in me web app it just appears on the feature
[This is a demo web-app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2GIl.png)  ......
[screenshot of fb page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAA3V.png)

Comment: Sorry to say, but this question needs a lot of clarification. Tools used, error messages received, etc.

Comment: I just need to know what API of facebook should I use for my app to link my web app to the facebook page.

Comment: What do you mean?